# What is the role of SHA hash in signing a document in OpenSSL library?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openssl, digital-signature, sha256

I am following [OpenSSL](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL.html#module-OpenSSL-label-Signatures) directives to generate signatures. I am using ruby 2.1.0 and am generating signatures like this:

```
document = "This is a simple string document to be signed"
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new([private_key])
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
signature = key.sign digest, document
```

The signature is transmitted and reaches the destination where it is to be verified. To verify, I do like this:

```
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new([pubkey])
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
key.verify digest, signature, document # => valid
```

This is working because if we change just one letter of the document or signature, this returns invalid result:

```
key.verify digest, signature, changed_document # => Invalid
```

But with a different SHA, the verification command still results in a valid result:

```
digest = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new('this will generate different SHA')
key.verify digest, signature, document # => valid
```

It confused me. Shouldn't a different SHA hash result in invalid result? What is the role of digest here?

Answer (score 2):

Passing an argument to `OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new` causes that data to be added to the digest.

However, the openssl signing functions reset the digest before it is used and so that extra data has no effect in this particular case.

Comment: Could you give more information to why is it done so? _Shouldn't a different SHA hash result in invalid result?_

Comment: It's the same SHA hashing function. In the second case you're supplying some initial data, which is discarded so the result is as if the initial data hadn't been there in the first place. As to why I assume it's make it easier to reuse digest objects

Comment: Ok. As you can see I am trying to digitally sign a document. Then can I assume that the method I used to sign the document is right?